# How do memory are alloacted when new object is initialized

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, heap-memory, stack-memory

I have some question about heap and stack memory. Look at the folling code

```
//This code is written in C++

class Box {
    public:
        double l, w, h v;
        Box(double ll, double ww, double hh, double vv) {
            l=ll;
            w=ww;
            h=hh;
            v=vv;
        }
        virtual double containedValue() {
            return v;
        }
}

class Cube: public Box {
    public:
        Cube(double s, double v): Box(s, s, s, v);
        virtual double containedValue() {
            return v*v*v;
        }
        virtual void cloneCube() {
            Cube* clone = new Cube(l, v);
        }
}

void doSomething() {
    Box* boxPtr1;
    Box* boxPtr2;
    Box box1(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0);
}
```

As the above code from [this](http://www.maxi-pedia.com/what+is+heap+and+stack) link, it said that the object is always allocated on heap memory. So I deduce that the object's parameter is also stored in heap memory space. But I also found another reference [here](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/comp/15/reference/roberts_heap_stack_diagrams.pdf) which demonstrate the parameters for object creation is stored in stack. So where exactly did the parameters stored?

```
-----------
| l = 1.0 |
-----------
| w = 2.0 |
-----------
| h = 3.0 |              Heap
-----------
| v = 4.0 |     |---> -----------
-----------     |     |   Box   | —-> V-table somewhere
|   box1  | ----|     -----------
-----------           | l = 1.0 |
| boxPtr2 |           -----------
-----------           | w = 2.0 |
| boxPtr1 |           -----------
-----------           | h = 3.0 |
   Stack              -----------
                      | v = 4.0 |        
                      ___________

Or

                |---> -----------
-----------     |     |   Box   | —-> V-table somewhere
|   box1  | ----|     -----------
-----------           | l = 1.0 |
| boxPtr2 |           -----------
-----------           | w = 2.0 |
| boxPtr1 |           -----------
-----------           | h = 3.0 |
   Stack              -----------
                      | v = 4.0 |        
                      ___________
                         Heap
```

Comment: No box is on the stack.

Comment: Everything should end up on the stack. Without new/malloc nothing is going to the heap

Comment: `box1` and `box2` are both on the stack (supposing your C++ implementation puts local variables on the stack, which is most likely the case). Your (nicely made) ASCII drawing are wrong.

Comment: Could you provide some reference? As from my first reference, it explicitly said that every object is declared on heap memory. And the first 2 comment are conflict each other. But thanks for the compliment.

Comment: @WakemeUpNow I suppose you refer to this : _Memory space for objects is always allocated in heap..._. from [here](http://www.maxi-pedia.com/what+is+heap+and+stack). This is plain wrong, and anyway the whole article is oversimplified and full of half truths. The [other reference](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/comp/15/reference/roberts_heap_stack_diagrams.pdf) is more serious. Rule of thumb: anything that is allocated with the C `malloc` function or  with the C++ `new` operator goes into the heap. Local variables go on the stack (even if the C++ standard doesn't explicitly mention the stack).

Comment: BTW the first two comments actually both say the same. The very first comment should read _No, box1 is on the stack_ (note the comma).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. :-D

Comment: I wouldn't trust any site calling C an object oriented language. :-) Also, if you look closely it *says* that there are 3 memory segments in a program, and then shows a picture of 4 segments. So rubbish.